# Creating a serializable fixed size char array in F#

Tags: casting, f#, unsafe

I am dealing with a very large amount of data I need to load / save to disk where speed is the key.

I wrote this code:

```
// load from cache
let loadFromCacheAsync<'a when 'a: (new: unit -> 'a) and 'a: struct and 'a :> ValueType> filespec =
    async {
        let! bytes = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filespec) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let result = 
            use pBytes = fixed bytes
            let sourceSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr pBytes, bytes.Length) 
            MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, 'a>(sourceSpan).ToArray()
        return result
    }    

// save to cache
let saveToCacheAsync<'a when 'a: unmanaged> filespec (data: 'a array) =
    Directory.CreateDirectory cacheFolder |> ignore
    let sizeStruct = sizeof<'a>
    use ptr = fixed data
    let nativeSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, data.Length * sizeStruct).ToArray()
    File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filespec, nativeSpan) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

and it requires the data structures to be unmanaged.
For example, I have:

```
[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type ShortTradeData =
    {
        [<FieldOffset(00)>]    Timestamp: DateTime
        [<FieldOffset(08)>]    Price:     double
        [<FieldOffset(16)>]    Quantity:  double
        [<FieldOffset(24)>]    Direction: int
    }
```

or

```
[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type ShortCandleData =
    {
        [<FieldOffset(00)>] Timestamp:  DateTime
        [<FieldOffset(08)>] Open:       double
        [<FieldOffset(16)>] High:       double
        [<FieldOffset(24)>] Low:        double
        [<FieldOffset(32)>] Close:      double
    }
```

etc...

I'm now facing a case where I need to store a string. I know the max length of the strings but I'm trying to find out how I can do this with un-managed types.

I'm wondering if I could do something like this (for 256 bytes):

```
[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type TestData =
    {
        [<FieldOffset(00)>]    Timestamp: DateTime
        [<FieldOffset(08)>]    Text:      char
        [<FieldOffset(264)>]   Dummy:     int
    }
```

Would it be safe then to get a pointer to Text, cast it to a char array, read / write what I want in it and then save / load it as needed?

Or am I asking for some random troubles at some point?

As a side question, any way to speed up the loadFromCache function is very welcome too :)

Edit:

I came up with this for now. It converts a list of complex event objects into something serializable.
The line:

> let bytes = Pipeline.serializeBinary event

turns the original event data into a byte array.

Then I create the struct that will hold the binary stream, write the length, create a span representing the struct and copy the bytes. Then I marshal the span into the struct type (ShortEventData).

I can't use Marshal copy since I can't put a destination offset, so I have to copy the bytes with a loop. But there has to be a better way.

And I think, there has to be a better way for everything else in this as well :D Any suggestion would help, I just don't really like this solution.

```
[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type ShortEventData =
    {
        [<FieldOffset(00)>]    Timestamp: DateTime
        [<FieldOffset(08)>]    Event:     byte
        [<FieldOffset(1032)>]  Length:    int
    }

events
|> List.map (fun event ->
        let bytes = Pipeline.serializeBinary event
        let serializableEvent : DataCache.ShortEventData =
            {
                Timestamp = event.GetTimestamp()
                Event     = byte 0
                Length    = bytes.Length
            }
        use ptr = fixed [|serializableEvent|]
        let nativeSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, serializableEvent.Length * sizeStruct)
        for i = 0 to bytes.Length - 1 do
            nativeSpan[8 + i] <- bytes[i]
        MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, DataCache.ShortEventData>(nativeSpan).ToArray()[0]
    )
```

---

Edit:

Adding benchmarks for different serialization models:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes
open BenchmarkDotNet.Running
open MBrace.FsPickler
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop
open Newtonsoft.Json

#nowarn "9"



[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type TestStruct =
    {
        [<FieldOffset(00)>] SomeValue:       int
        [<FieldOffset(04)>] AnotherValue:    int
        [<FieldOffset(08)>] YetAnotherValue: double
    }
    
    static member MakeOne(r: Random) =
        {
            SomeValue       = r.Next()
            AnotherValue    = r.Next()
            YetAnotherValue = r.NextDouble()
        }
        
        
        
[<MemoryDiagnoser>]
type Benchmarks () =        
    let testData =
        let random = Random(1000)
        Array.init 1000 (fun _ -> TestStruct.MakeOne(random))

    
    // inits, outside of the benchmarks
    // FSPickler
    let FSPicklerSerializer = FsPickler.CreateBinarySerializer()

    // APEX
    let ApexSettings = Apex.Serialization.Settings().MarkSerializable(typeof<TestStruct>)
    let ApexBinarySerializer = Apex.Serialization.Binary.Create(ApexSettings)
        

    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.Thomas() =  // thomas' save to disk
        let sizeStruct = sizeof<TestStruct>
        use ptr = fixed testData
        Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, testData.Length * sizeStruct).ToArray()

    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.Newtonsoft() =
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData)

    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.FSPickler() =
        FSPicklerSerializer.Pickle testData
        
    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.Apex() =
        let outputStream = new MemoryStream()
        ApexBinarySerializer.Write(testData, outputStream)        
        
    
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    let _ = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>()
    0
```

```
|     Method |         Mean |        Error |       StdDev |    Gen 0 |   Gen 1 |   Gen 2 | Allocated |
|----------- |-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|---------:|--------:|--------:|----------:|
|     Thomas |     878.4 ns |     11.74 ns |     10.41 ns |   2.5444 |  0.1411 |       - |     16 KB |
| Newtonsoft | 880,641.2 ns | 16,346.50 ns | 15,290.52 ns | 103.5156 | 79.1016 | 48.8281 |    508 KB |
|  FSPickler |  71,786.6 ns |  1,373.89 ns |  1,349.35 ns |  13.6719 |  2.0752 |       - |     84 KB |
|       Apex |   1,088.8 ns |     20.59 ns |     22.03 ns |   2.6093 |  0.0725 |       - |     16 KB |
```

It looks like Apex is very close to what I did, but it's probably a lot more flexible and more optimized, so it could make sense to switch to it, UNLESS what I have can be a lot more optimized.

I have to see how @JL0PD's excellent comments can improve the speed.

Comment: I am sure you have benchmarks but I would focus on the IO part instead. 
If you don’t then I wouldn’t read the file in one chunk but  create an pipeline where you read it in chunks async. 
Also if performance is an issue avoid list an use an array.

Comment: Its already all arrays now and I stream the data into a queue and consume the other end, but we’re talking about hundreds of millions of records in total (each stream session being a few tens of millions). So I have to take speed anywhere I can. Json/FSPickler are way too slow for this. It’s very likely I’ll rewrite this in C but I don’t have time now and need to squeeze speed.

Comment: Have you tried third-party serializers like [Apex.Serialization](https://github.com/dbolin/Apex.Serialization)?

Comment: @JL0PD, I haven't tried Apex, I've tried a few other options and had settled for FSPickler, but the code I posted on top completely beats it since it's essentially just a binary save of the object without any processing nor copy and the load is a binary load with a cast on top. However, it's ultra restrictive and can't handle any managed type, which is why it's fast. But I have one case with one object type where I have managed type, all the others are fine. (->)

Comment: this is why I wrote the code in this question; I'm trying to turn that managed object (string) into an unmanaged object. Since this is the only type like this and I want to use a single pipeline for all types this specific one is a bit tricky and looks a bit hackish, but custom code to handle that one case will be faster than anything that needs reflection like the flexible serializers.

Comment: @Thomas, dotnet supports runtime code generation, which can have same performance as handwritten code or even better. Look at [benchmarks](https://github.com/dbolin/Apex.Serialization/blob/master/Benchmarks.md): this serializer is 15x-100x faster than precomputed `protobuf`, which is holy grail of performance for many developers

Comment: code in question is far from being optimal. 1. Using more space than actually needed: if most strings are in 10 character length, then only 4% of space will hold info, all others is just zeroes, that will eat space in network. 2. Preallocating array with `serializeBinary` and not releasing it, use `ArrayPool`. 3. Creating 1-size array to take pointer for data, instead of declaring variable as `mutable` and taking pointer. 4. Creating `Span` that points beyond memory you own, potentially causing `AccessViolation`, use `+` instead of `*`. 5. Copying with loop, instead of simd-optimized Span.Copy

Comment: 6. Creating copy of data, to access first element. Don't call `ToArray`, access first element directly. 7. Big, very big struct that passed by-value instead of by-reference. MS recommends passing structs bigger than 16 bytes by-reference. Copying such struct may cause significant performance loses. 8. Writing to file is done with copying to new array, instead of using `Stream.Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte>)`

Comment: @JL0PD, I have added benchmarks, but this is starting to look like this part may be better moved to a new question. What do you think? Also, I didn't benchmark reading the data back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of interest I took the lambda at the end of your question and tested three similar implementations and ran it on Benchmark.Net.

- `Reference` - as you have shown
- `Mutable Struct` - as I might have done it with a mutable struct
- `Record` - using a plain old dumb record

See the results for yourself. Plain old dumb record is the fastest (though only marginally faster than my attempt and ~10x faster than your example). Write dumb code first. Benchmark it. Then try to improve.

```
#nowarn "9"

open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes
open BenchmarkDotNet.Running
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop

type ShortEventDataRec =
    {
        Timestamp: DateTime
        Event:     byte[]
        Length:    int
    }

[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type ShortEventData =
    {
        [<FieldOffset(00)>]    Timestamp: DateTime
        [<FieldOffset(08)>]    Event:     byte
        [<FieldOffset(1032)>]  Length:    int
    }

[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type MutableShortEventData =
    struct
        [<FieldOffset(00)>]    val mutable Timestamp: DateTime
        [<FieldOffset(08)>]    val mutable Event:     byte
        [<FieldOffset(1032)>]  val mutable Length:    int
    end 

[<MemoryDiagnoser>]
type Benchmarks () =

    let event  = 
        Array.init 1024 (fun i -> byte (i % 256))
    let time = DateTime.Now
    let sizeStruct = sizeof<ShortEventData>


    [<Benchmark>]
    member __.Reference() =
        let bytes = event
        let serializableEvent =
            {
                ShortEventData.Timestamp = time
                Event     = byte 0
                Length    = bytes.Length
            }
        use ptr = fixed [|serializableEvent|]
        let nativeSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, sizeStruct)
        for i = 0 to bytes.Length - 1 do
            nativeSpan.[8 + i] <- bytes.[i]

        MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ShortEventData>(nativeSpan).[0]


    [<Benchmark>]
    member __.MutableStruct() =
        let bytes = event

        let targetBytes = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray(sizeStruct)
        let targetSpan = Span(targetBytes)
        let targetStruct = MemoryMarshal.Cast<_, MutableShortEventData>(targetSpan)

        targetStruct.[0].Timestamp <- time
        let targetEvent = bytes.CopyTo(targetSpan.Slice(8, 1024))
        targetStruct.[0].Length <- event.Length

        targetStruct.[0]


    [<Benchmark>]
    member __.Record() =
        let bytes = event
        let serializableEvent =
            {
                ShortEventDataRec.Timestamp = time
                Event     = 
                    let eventBytes = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray(bytes.Length)
                    System.Array.Copy(bytes, eventBytes, bytes.Length)
                    eventBytes
                Length    = bytes.Length
            }
        serializableEvent
    
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    let _ = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>()
    0
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reference | 526.88 ns | 6.318 ns | 5.909 ns | 0.0629 | - | 1 KB |
| MutableStruct | 49.50 ns | 0.966 ns | 1.074 ns | 0.0636 | - | 1 KB |
| Record | 42.73 ns | 0.672 ns | 0.628 ns | 0.0650 | 0.0002 | 1 KB |

Comment: [This](https://andrewlock.net/a-deep-dive-on-stringbuilder-part-1-the-overall-design-and-first-look-at-the-internals/#creating-a-stringbuilder) blog post says that using `AllocateUninitializedArray` is slow for small arrays

Comment: thanks a lot for looking into this. The Record one wouldn't work though because the current serializer can only take unmanaged objects, but the MutableStruct works perfectly. Unfortunately, I never took the time to learn the lower level memory management in dotnet, but it looks like a good opportunity to fix that!

Comment: @tranquility, I've edited the question to add benchmarks for the main serialization if you're interested to have a look.

Comment: @Thomas I'm no expert at low level memory management. I learned *just enough* to talk to Excel's C API from F# https://www.primacy.co/post/exploring-fsharp-in-excel.

Comment: @JL0PD I ran a couple more tests with `GC.AllocateArray` `Array.CreateInstance` and F#'s `Array.copy` they were all about 60ns on my machine. Interestingly `[| yield! bytes |]` took about 3,000 ns! I guess there is no optimised overload to bulk copy an array like that.